# Input data to a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How could I create a shell script with input data ?

Please enter names separated by a blank: John Marry Sanford Saunders

```
read names
```

Comment: While @andlrc made a reasonable _guess_ as to what you're after, your question is vague and shows little effort; consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

AFAI understand you want to use an array:

```
read -r -a names
```

Example:

```
read -r -a names <<< "John Marry Sanford Saunders"
echo "${names[0]}" # John
echo "${names[1]}" # Marry
echo "${names[2]}" # Sanford
echo "${names[3]}" # Saunders
```

Comment: Ok, but if I need insert 9 person names ?

Comment: This it will be used in a menu...